# Ethereum transaction taking way too long time

Tags: myetherwallet

I have generated and (aparently) successively transferred some Ether from an exchange to my etherwallet 24hs ago... now still the eths never arrived on my wallet... the Exchange shows transaction success showing "OUTPUT TRANSACTION HASH" ok and all... Can someone elaborate? I have notice that other exchanges such as Polo and CoinBase are also having delay problems with transactions using the Ethereum network... Anyway to check wigo, and/or get an idea to when this issue maybe resolved? Thx P.S. I need to make a transaction using the eths... that at the moment are on air...

Comment: Hi there. There is a large backlog of pending transactions on the network due to a recent token ICO. I'm afraid you'll just have to wait until the congestion clears. (Pending transactions: https://etherscan.io/txsPending - looks like it'll probably take a few more hours at the current rate.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. To me it's obvious that there is something really wrong with the infrastructure of the Ethereum and consequently with all the other blockchain networks... if the system gets overwhelmed by an ICO, it looks that it already running above it's limit and in crash mode... there must be major design flaw in the ethereum system that was not foreseen... The system is growing too big too fast... I think it will have to crash before moves forward IMO.

Comment: There's a difference between "wrong with the infrastructure" and "wrong with the way people are using it". The Ethereum system is doing just fine (servers aren't crashing or getting "overwhelmed"), it's just that users, developers (and therefore wallets and other applications) don't have the reflexes yet for how to tell if the network is busy currently or not, and change their actions accordingly (how you catch a train during rush hour is vastly different than catching a train during off-peak hours).